# windows scheduler to run batch file after the first process is ended

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a small question on `windows scheduler` - Say i have scheduled a task to run once in 30 minutes interval in `windows task scheduler`. 
Does windows start the `second process` even if my `first job process` has not finished yet? Or `windows` takes care of starting the `second job process` only after the `first job` is finished? Or do i have to take care of it explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the *Settings tab* in the *Create Task wizard* (or editing the tasks’ *Properties*). There should be an entry *If the task is already running, then the following entry applies:* and you can choose one of the following options (push button):

`Do not start a new instance` - the first instance of the task continues to run.

`Run a new instance in parallel` - the first task instance continues to run and the new task instance also starts.

`Queue a new instance` - the new tasks instance runs after the first task instance finished.

`Stop the existing instance` - the first task instance is stopped and the new task instance is started.

Comment: Thank you ! I was looking for these options only.